# Check if $routeParams name exist in database

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mean-stack

I'm making a website on a MEAN stack, and I have a template that works with a wildcard route in Angular. When the user types plumber-in-"cityname", the cityname is then checked if it exists in the DB with a loop. If it exists, it retrieves all the information that comes with the cityname. But now I only need a "page not found" page if the user chooses a city that does not exist in the DB.

How can I make this happen?

This is my loop in the controller:

```
app.controller('DataCtrl2', function($scope,$http,getData,$location,$routeParams){

$scope.changePath = function(path) {
   $location.path('/'+ path +'-' + $scope.selectedItem.city);
};

getData.getCity().then(function(response){

$scope.items = response.data;

var keepGoing = true;
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++){
  var data = $scope.items[i];
  if(keepGoing) {
      if (angular.lowercase($routeParams.name) == angular.lowercase(data.city)) {
       keepGoing = false;
       $scope.selectedItem = data;
      }
     }
    }
  });
});
```

JSON:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("592409faf1f5831ca882ad39"), 
  "city" : "Aalsmeer", 
  "phoneLG" : "0101-010 001", 
  "phoneAV" : "0101-010 001", 
  "phoneCV" : "0101-010 001"
}
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("592409faf1f5831ca882ad3a"), 
  "city" : "Aalburg", 
  "phoneLG" : "0101-010 001", 
  "phoneAV" : "0101-010 001", 
  "phoneCV" : "0101-010 001"
}
```

Comment: Instead of making a 404 not found page for a data that obviously will not exist, you should check for that value and add something like a popup to notice the user that the request doesn't exist? just an idea

Comment: But if you want to keep that, you may just add a condition, like "else {$location.path('/your404Page.html')} ?

Comment: The else statement does not work, because it will return ''Page Not found'' 420 times (as long as there are records)

Comment: Of course ahah because you are in the loop, you need to check if the param exists before entering the loop. Im thinking of a solution, wait a minute

Comment: Could I see your object city (response.data)? I'm trying something but cannot promise anything..

Comment: I edited it with the jSON object, but only put 2, because there are 420 cities :)

Comment: Thanks, but I may have a better idea now, could you use : 
 else {
            $location.path('/your404Page.html');
            break;
        } ? Not sure that would work but give it a try :D

Comment: this does not work, it returns my "page not found" page, even if the records exists :$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147370/discussion-between-devmoutarde-and-larsmanson).